# Opening SSL URLs with Mechanize in Python

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize, urllib2

How do you use mechanize to open an SSL URL in Python?

I'm attempting a trivial page retrieval with Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu like:

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
resp = browser.open('https://mydomain.com')
```

but it throws the error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)>
```

Oddly, I don't get this error when I run this same code under Python 2.6.4 on Fedora...

Presumably, this is likely not a direct problem with mechanize, but with urllib2 and the underlying SSL C library. Googling shows few hits. Is there a workaround?

Edit: I found this [old bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue11220), with a suggested workaround (basically Python is trying to use SSLv23 for a SSLv3-only site), but that code instead results in the error `httplib.BadStatusLine: ''`

Comment: by any chance are you on windows?

Comment: @samy.vilar, Nope, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I think its a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/966058 though not sure, you can check out http://code.google.com/p/selenium/?redir=1 its pretty cool.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is likely due to SSLv2 being disabled on the web server, but Python 2.x tries to establish a connection with PROTOCOL_SSLv23 by default. This happens at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ssl.py#L867

Instead of copying and editing Python library modules, you can monkey-patch ssl.wrap_socket() in the ssl module by overriding the ssl_version keyword parameter. The following code can be used as-is. Put this at the start of your program before making any requests.

```
import ssl
from functools import wraps
def sslwrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def bar(*args, **kw):
        kw['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return bar

ssl.wrap_socket = sslwrap(ssl.wrap_socket)
```